# Does the PHP file_exists function work in Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

When I deploy a php file to GAE, the `file_exists` function does not work.  If I test the exact same code locally from my computer, using Google App Engine Launcher, it works.  Here is the PHP and app.yaml file

### indexTest.php

```
<?php
DEFINE("TESTFILE", 'testfile.txt');
echo TESTFILE.'<br>';

$doesTheFileExist = file_exists(TESTFILE);
echo '$doesTheFileExist: ' . $doesTheFileExist. '<br>';

if (!file_exists(TESTFILE)) {
  echo 'I guess it doesnt exist';
}

RETURN;
```

### app.yaml

```
application: application-name
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon.ico

- url: /google-api-php-client
  script: google-api-php-client

- url: /testfile.txt
  static_files: testfile.txt
  upload: testfile.txt

- url: /
  script: indexTest.php
```

### Output locally

[image: fileexistlocal]

### Output on GAE

[image: existfileGAE]

Why does this work when tested locally, and after being deployed, it doesn't work?

I tried changing the location of the file and changing the **app.yaml** file, and adding something like:

```
- url: /templates
  static_dir: templates
```

And putting the file in the **templates** directory.  But again, it works in Local Host, but not deployed to App Engine.

Comment: where is the file located?

Comment: Located in the root directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `application_readable` flag on your handler if you want to be able to read static resources from your app.

Of course if you don't actually want to be able to serve the file as a static resource but just want to be able to read it, then don't even include it in your app.yaml file and it will be uploaded and accessible from your app.

See the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig).

Comment: I'm testing an authorization to Google, and a file creation to Google Drive.  One example in PHP uses a file as the basis for a new file creation in Drive.  So, I'm not serving the content of the file.  I will probably not use that strategy, but create an empty file, then write contents to it, or something like that.  I'm a little concerned about making the app readable.  I immediately think "security risk".

Comment: "application_readable" means you can serve it statically and you can read it from your app - it is required because usually static files are served by the infrastructure and not deployed to the same location as your application code. If you don't need to serve the files statically then do not put it in the app.yaml file.